# refactoring the App() function in React and Typescipt

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

My React/Typescript app has several sections. So the

```
export default function App() {}
```

has become very long. All tutorials I have watched do not go further to refactoring this. And I have had trouble searching the right thing.

But I am having trouble refactoring the first element.(just a snippet)

my code currently:
App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const minusnum = () => {
    if (count > 0) setCount(count - 1);
  };
  const addnum = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

return (
  <div>
     <Button onClick={minusnum}>minus</Button>
     <Button onClick={addnum}>add</Button>
     <input type="number" min="0" step="1" name="clicks" value={count} onChange={(event) => {const value = Number(event.target.value); setCount(value);}}></input>
  </div> );

}
```

Now I want App.tsx to look something like:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Counter from "./parts/Counter";

export default function App() {
   <CounterSection>
       <Counter/>
   </CounterSection>
}
```

and inside ./parts/Counter there is an index.tsx file

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const minusnum = () => {
    if (count > 0) setCount(count - 1);
  };
  const addnum = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

const Index = () => {
  return (
    <div>
     <Button onClick={minusnum}>minus</Button>
     <Button onClick={addnum}>add</Button>
     <input type="number" min="0" step="5" name="clicks" value={count} onChange={(event) => {const value = Number(event.target.value); setCount(value);}}></input>
  </div> )
};

export default Index;
```

Which ends up showing nothing. how do I deal with the event handling stuff in the index file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as far as I can tell, the `CounterSection` component you're using hasn't been defined yet **and** you are not actually `return`ing anything from your `App` component.

This is most likely the reason nothing is being rendered on your end.

```
// App.tsx
export default function App(){
    return (
        <div> // Change this back to CounterSection if you have it defined.
            <Counter/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Second, ensure that all your hooks and functions are declared and called inside the component that is using them.

```
// parts/Counter/index.tsx
const Index = () => {
    // State hook
    const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
    
    // Function (method) declaration
    const minusNum = () => setCount(currentCount => {
        let newCount = currentCount - 1;
        return Math.max(0, newCount); // Same thing as what you had before.
    });
    const addNum = () => setCount(currentCount => currentCount + 1);

    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={minusNum}>minus</Button>
            <Button onClick={addNum}>add</Button>
            <input type="number" step="5" value={count} onChange={({ target }) => setCount(Number(target.value))} />
        </div> 
    );
};
```

The last thing you may have noticed me do is provide a callback in `setCount` instead of the `count` variable.

Now, while your approach would have worked, it's a good habit to try and break into (where possible) and will help you mitigate any stale state you encounter in the future.